# Как правильно отобразить треугольник при верстке?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем доброго времени суток) Возник вопрос, как будет правильно отобразить треугольник (на фото в нижнем углу) при верстке страницы: с помощью позиционирования картинки, или нарисовать его свойствами CSS???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @vp_arth вас не смущает, что это русскоязычное сообщество?

Comment: @websnap, почему это должно меня смущать? Мне это даже нравится.

Comment: @Даша, вопросы о том как лучше - это всегда холивар. На них трудно ответить объективно.

Comment: @vp_arth то-есть, особой разницы  нету? Делать так, как удобней?

Comment: Градиентом сделайте. А лучше всеми способами, которые приходят в голову.

Comment: @websnap ну треугольником свойствами CSS при адаптивности, все ломается))

Comment: @ДашаНовикова какими свойствами делаете?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev правду говоря, 3 часа ковырялась, ничего толкового не поучилось, я со злости все удалила и решила картинкой сделать)) но делала как-то так:`.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border: 18vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 18vw solid #FA8686;
  border-bottom: 18vw solid #FA8686;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; 
}`

Comment: @ДашаНовикова https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vawZpv?editors=1100

Comment: при адаптивности появляются непонятные пустые пространства)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При условии, что ширина контейнера всегда меньше высоты, можно градиентом в псевдоэлементе. Работает адаптивно.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.intro {
  flex: 2;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
}

.right:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 50%, pink 50%, pink);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="intro"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Треугольник выходит за границы в FireFox

Comment: @Duoxx, почитайте текст ;)

Comment: Какой именно текст?

Comment: @Duoxx, тот, что перед сниппетом. Вообще для теста лучше развернуть на всю страницу

Answer (score 0):

Возможно покажется костылем, но это единственное что мне пришло в голову

```js
function angle(width, height)
{
  return Math.atan(height/width)*(180/Math.PI);
}
//alert (angle(400,200))
document.getElementsByClassName("triangle")[0].style.background = "linear-gradient("+-45+angle(400, 200)+"deg, transparent 50%, #ff9999 0)"
```

```css
.triangle-wrapper {
  width:400px;
  height:500px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.triangle-wrapper .triangle {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-wrapper">
  <div class="triangle" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а где адаптивность?

Comment: Адаптивность можно дописать вручную, что в принципе я могу и сделать

Comment: К тому же в вопросе про адаптивность не слова

Comment: Да, там в комментарии есть. Кстати а зачем вообще в вашем ответе js? что он делает кроме искривления треугольника? ps минусанул не я